# Index to multiple items by defining index boundaries equivalent in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My background before JavaScript was primary in R. When needing to index to multiple items in an array, we could use `items[1:66]`. Which collected all items 1 through 66 using `:`.

What's the closest equivalent to perform this task in JavaScript? Where you can index to multiple items defined by index boundaries. I can think of multiple use cases where this would be helpful.

Comment: Well, you can't...sort of. I think the most appropriate for this in javascript would be `items.slice(0, 66)` which will create a sublist from the existing list. Also, please note that javascript is 0 indexed. Probably you should forget your R knowledge, JS and R are separate languages used for separate purposes.

Comment: Don't worry i'm aware, the `items[1:66]` statement was just following R's index syntax. So instead my only option is to just index within a for loop? If that's the case, it seems quite impractical even for javascript.

Comment: as ervin says just use item.slice if you want to get a subpart of your array

Comment: maybe give an example of what you need if it doesn't work for you

Comment: Oh right, that actually collects the indexes. Okay sweet, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that returns a proxy to the current array. This way, there is **no copying or duplication** of the underlying array:

```js
function indexedArray(originalArray, starting, ending) {
  return new Proxy(originalArray, {
    get: function(target, index) {
      // length does some math
      if (index === 'length') return Math.min(originalArray.length, ending) - Math.min(originalArray.length, starting);
      // if it is an index, picks the indexed value
      if (/^[0-9]$/.test(index)) {
        const newIndex = starting + Number(index);
        if (newIndex >= ending) return undefined;
        return originalArray[newIndex];
      }
      // if the method would mutate the original array, we just error
      const mutatorMethods = ['copyWithin', 'fill', 'pop', 'push', 'reverse', 'shift', 'sort', 'splice', 'unshift'];
      if (mutatorMethods.includes(index)) throw Error('This is a proxy and wont mutate the original array');
      // for every other function, the simplest way is to now do copy the array
      // or, when you need, you can implement the special logic for each one
      return originalArray.slice(starting, ending)[index];
    },
    set: function() {
      // for simplicity, this proxy is read-only, but you could impl de set/write logic as well
      throw Error('This is a proxy and wont mutate the original array');
    }
  });
}
//                0    1    2    3    4    5
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

const myIndexedArray = indexedArray(myArray, 2, 4);

console.assert(myIndexedArray[0] === 'c', 'test#1.1')
console.assert(myIndexedArray[1] === 'd', 'test#1.2')
console.assert(myIndexedArray[2] === undefined, 'test#1.3')
console.assert(myIndexedArray.length === 2, 'test#1.4')

const myIndexedArray2 = indexedArray(myArray, 5, 7);
console.assert(myIndexedArray2[0] === 'f', 'test#2.1')
console.assert(myIndexedArray2[1] === undefined, 'test#2.2')
console.assert(myIndexedArray2.length === 1, 'test#2.3')

const myIndexedArray3 = indexedArray([], 1, 5);
console.assert(myIndexedArray3[0] === undefined, 'test#3.1')
console.assert(myIndexedArray3[1] === undefined, 'test#3.2')
console.assert(myIndexedArray3.length === 0, 'test#3.3')

const myIndexedArray4 = indexedArray(myArray, 5, 5);
console.assert(myIndexedArray4[0] === undefined, 'test#4.1')
console.assert(myIndexedArray4[1] === undefined, 'test#4.2')
console.assert(myIndexedArray4.length === 0, 'test#4.3')

console.assert(eq(indexedArray(myArray, 3, 5).map(x => x.toUpperCase()), ['D', 'E']), 'test#5');

console.log('All good', new Date())

function eq(a, b) { return JSON.stringify(a)===JSON.stringify(b) }
```

Comment: There you go. I changed the indexes calculation a bit, so it matches `.slice()`. Make sure you test (or see the tests I wrote), before using it!

Comment: Ah, just one last thing that I realized: just added the `set` function, so the indexed array is read-only. That is, `myIndexedArray[1] = 'new value';`  will now throw an error (informing the developer the indexed array is read-only).